# CRUD Codeigniter

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, codeigniter, crud

I use codeigniter to cake my webapps, but i'm boring to create always "CRUD" operations (form, controller, model, database). Do you know a great tool to generate CRUD operations ? (like RoR ?).

Thank's !

Comment: Check this http://codeigniter-crud.ialabs.net/

Answer (score 3):

I created a library for that reason, because creating CRUD operations is boring and frustrating.

Sparks version: 
http://getsparks.org/packages/sangar-scaffold/versions/HEAD/show

Github: 
https://github.com/sangar82/sangar-scaffold-spark

With this sparks you can do the following:

> Sangar-scaffolds creates the tables on the database, the controllers, the models and the views.
>
> It also modifies the routes.php file.
>
> You can create forms with the followings elements:
>   - text
>   - textarea
>   - radiobuttons
>           - checkboxes
>           - select
>           - select 1:N (populate the form select with a existent Model)
>           - upload images (with thumbnail creation and uploads rules)
>           - upload files (with uploads rules)
>           - hidden relational (It's a special element. Only one hidden relational by scaffolding is allowed. It will produce a form with relation 1:N linked with his parent form automatically. Belongs_to relation )
>
> Each element has validation rules and the possibility to do it multilanguage.
>
> Create also a paginated list view.

**Codeigniter Starter Project**

I created a  Codeigniter Starter Project, because  configure a new project is also boring . It has the basic that I think that need a new codeigniter project and the crud generator has more features than the Sparks version. I use it daily. Take a look at Github

Custom Codeigniter with preinstalled features:

Github: https://github.com/sangar82/CodeIgniter-Starter/

It´s in continous development, bugs alerts and improvements are welcome.

Features:

> Sparks installed (http://getsparks.org/)
>       Sangar Auth Library. (Ion-Auth modified for me working under PHP-activerecord)
>       Sangar Scaffolding Library. A new way to do scaffolding!
>       Php-ActiveRecord installed (https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord) Version Nightly build May 2012
>       Backend & Full Access Control (login, logout, remember password, and protected access to the backend)
>       Template Library by Phil Sturgeon implemented (http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/)
>       Basic layout (frontend, backend)
>       Toast Unit test (http://jensroland.com/projects/toast/)
>       Includes basic before_filter and after_filter support (Matthew Machuga) https://github.com/machuga/codeigniter-filter
>       System Messages implemented as a partial in layouts
>       Folder for public content (images, js, uploads, ...)
>       Subdomains for multi-language
>       Translation on 3 languages (english, spanish, catalan)
>       Methods for translate controllers and methods names on URL
>       CRUD Users implemented.
>       Example: CRUD Categories. Categories as a tree of categories (with order via ajax)
>       Example: CRUD Products with upload an image and thumbnail creation
>       Examples of testing (SangarAuth Test, users test, categories test, products test).

Comment: @jeremie-ges, have you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

With the following link, you can make your CRUD operations easier in codeigniter framework.

[http://formigniter.org/app](http://formigniter.org/app/)/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GroceryCRUD http://www.grocerycrud.com/ I think it will cover your expectations ;-)

Comment: Hmm, yeah i know this great tool. But i'm looking for "scaffold" with low footprint ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the DataMapper ORM for CodeIgniter to be very easy to work with.

http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/